# Why does passing a tuple cause a key error in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I know that I can select multiple columns if I pass a *list* of the column names. I was surprised to find that I can't pass a *tuple* of column names.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],columns=['a','b','c'])

print df[['a','b']]
print df[('a','b')] # Key error
```

Why is this? Is there something important I'm missing? As far as I can tell, the only difference is that the second case, the multi-key is immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have column name as `tuple`, so then use for selecting `tuple`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],columns=[('a', 'b'),'b','c'])
print (df)
   (a, b)  b  c
0       2  3  4
1       3  4  5

print (df[('a','b')])
0    2
1    3
Name: (a, b), dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],columns=[('a','b','c'])
df.columns

#Index([u'a', u'b', u'c'], dtype='object')
```

You do not have key `('a','b')`, only `'a', 'b', 'c'` keys exits..

Answer (score 3):

Tuples are also used to select a column from a DataFrame with a MultiIndex:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a','b','c'], ['X','Y','Z']])
df = pd.DataFrame([[2,3,4],[3,4,5]], columns=columns)
#    a  b  c
#    X  Y  Z
# 0  2  3  4
# 1  3  4  5
```

then

```
In [203]: df[('a','X')]
Out[203]: 
0    2
1    3
Name: (a, X), dtype: int64
```

A list of tuples selects multiple columns, with each tuple specifying one column:

```
In [204]: df[[('a','X'), ('b','Y')]]
Out[204]: 
   a  b
   X  Y
0  2  3
1  3  4
```

---

[`DataFrame.__getitem__`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L1995) uses type checking to produce this behavior:

```
    # lists are handled here ----------------------vvvv
    if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
        # either boolean or fancy integer index
        return self._getitem_array(key)
    elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
        return self._getitem_frame(key)
    # tuples are handled here when self has a MultiIndex
    elif is_mi_columns:
        return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
    # or else here
    else:
        return self._getitem_column(key)
```